# Cambrionix PowerPad15S is not showing connected devices in Ubuntu

Tags: python, connection, usb

I am using Cambrionix PowerPad15s for my devices but while running their first code which is to find all the device connected to the usb i am having some issue in jsonrpc file(Which is provided by the company itself).
I have to import this-

```
from cbrxapi import cbrxapi
```

This code is to get all the connected device in the usb port and save in result variable-

```
result = cbrxapi.cbrx_discover("local")
```

Rest of the code is-

```
if result==False:
   print "No Cambrionix unit found."
   sys.exit(0)
unitId = result[0]
handle = cbrxapi.cbrx_connection_open(unitId)
nrOfPorts = cbrxapi.cbrx_connection_get(handle, "nrOfPorts")
cbrxapi.cbrx_connection_close(handle)
print "The Cambrionix unit " + unitId + " has " + str(nrOfPorts) + "  ports."
```

The error I am facing in is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "cbrx_api_quickstart.py", line 9, in 
>       result = cbrxapi.cbrx_discover("local")
>     File "/usr/local/share/cbrxapi/jsonrpc-0.1/jsonrpc.py", line 936, in **call**
>       return self.__req(self.__name, args, kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/share/cbrxapi/jsonrpc-0.1/jsonrpc.py", line 908, in __req
>       raise RPCTransportError(err)
>   jsonrpc.RPCTransportError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The product I am using is [Cambrionix](https://cambrionix.com/products/powerpad15s-industrial-strength-managed-hub/)

Sorry for not explaining properly. I am still in learning phase..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution-
I have to install one more file to my system to get the code working..

```
$ sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

And I need to ensure that one more script is running on my system.

```
install_service.sh in /usr/local/share/cbrxd/setup
```